# Ошибка при выделении памяти в Си (Access violation)

Tags: c, память, структуры-данных, односвязный-список

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема при выполнении программы.

```
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <memory.h>

    struct Customer {
        char fio[20];       // ФИО покупателя
        int id;             // порядковый номер
        char address[20];   // адрес покупателя
        char delivDate[20]; // дата доставки
        struct Customer *next;  //следующий покупатель
    };

    typedef struct Customer *PCust;   // массив структур


    PCust CreateCustomer(char *NewFio, char *NewAdress, char *NewData, int id);
    PCust Find(PCust Head, char NewFio[]);
    void AddFirst(PCust * Head, PCust NewCustomer);
    void AddLast(PCust *Head, PCust NewCustomer);
    void AddAfter(PCust p, PCust NewCustomer);
    void DeleteNode(PCust *Head, PCust p);

    ...

    int main() {
        while (1)
            switch (menu()) 
            {
            case 1:newList(); break;
            case 2:readFromFile(); break;
            case 3:addCustomer(); break;
            case 4:deleteCustomer(); break;
            case 5:changeCustomerField(); break;
            case 6:searchInCustomers(); break;
            case 7:return 0;
            default:printf("Neverniy vibor\n");
            }
    }

    int menu()
    {
        int choice;
        do
        {
            //system("cls");
            printf("Menu\n");
            printf("1.New list\n");
            printf("2.Read from file\n");
            printf("3.Add customer\n");
            printf("4.Delete customer\n");
            printf("5.Change customer field\n");
            printf("6.Search in customers\n");
            printf("7.Exit\n");
            printf("Vash vibor?\n");
            scanf_s("%d", &choice);
            //system("cls");
        } while (choice>7);
        return choice;
    }

    void addCustomer(void) {
        PCust Head = NULL;
        struct Customer currentCustomer;

        printf("Vvedite FIO pokupatelya: ");
        scanf("%s", currentCustomer.fio);
        printf("Vvedite datu dostavki: ");
        scanf("%s", currentCustomer.delivDate);
        printf("Vvedite adres pokupatelya: ");
        scanf("%s", currentCustomer.address);
        printf("Vvedite nomer pokupatelya: ");
        scanf("%d", &currentCustomer.id);

        PCust customerNode = CreateCustomer(currentCustomer.fio, currentCustomer.address,
            currentCustomer.delivDate, currentCustomer.id);

        AddLast(&Head, customerNode);
        //    writeToFile(&customerNode);
    }

    void writeToFile(PCust *Head) {

    //    FILE *f;
    //    f=fopen("customers.txt", "w");

    PCust q = *Head;        // Начали с головы
    if (*Head == NULL)
        return;

    while (q->next) // Пока не дошли до конца
    {
        printf("%s\n", q->fio);
        printf("%d\n", q->id);
        printf("%s\n", q->address);
        printf("%s\n", q->delivDate);
        //        q = q->next;  // Переходим к следующему узлу
    }
    printf("Vishli");
    //    fclose(f);
}

PCust CreateCustomer(char *NewFio, char *NewAdress, char *NewData, int id){
    PCust NewCustomer = (PCust)malloc(sizeof(PCust));
    strcpy(NewCustomer->fio, NewFio);
    strcpy(NewCustomer->address, NewAdress);
    strcpy(NewCustomer->delivDate, NewData);
    NewCustomer->id = id;
    NewCustomer->next = NULL;
    return NewCustomer;
}

// Добавление нового узла
void AddFirst(PCust * Head, PCust NewCustomer){
    NewCustomer->next = *Head;
    Head = &NewCustomer;
}

// Добавление узла между элементами
void AddAfter(PCust p, PCust NewCustomer){
    NewCustomer->next = p->next;
    p->next = NewCustomer;
}

// Добавить узел в конец списка
void AddLast(PCust *Head, PCust NewCustomer){
    PCust q = *Head;

    // Если список пустой
    if (*Head == NULL)
    {
        AddFirst(Head, NewCustomer);
        return;
    }

    // Цикл прохода до последнего узла списка
    while (q->next)
        q = q->next;

    // Добавление узла после заданного узла,
    // в данном случае после q
    AddAfter(q, NewCustomer);
}
```

Я использую односвязный список и при добавлении клиента (функция **addCustomer()**), выдает ошибку:

> Exception thrown at 0x77466EDD (ntdll.dll) in CourseWork_Test.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000003.

указывая на строку

```
PCust NewCustomer = (PCust)malloc(sizeof(PCust));
```

Ошибка появляется при добавлении второго или третьего клиента.
Скриншот вывода программы:
[image: program_output]

Спасибо

Comment: Не понимаю. Вы добавляете куда? Создаете локальный `PCust Head = NULL;`, т.е.создаете новый список, добавляете в него, а в силу того, что он локальный, благополучно теряете?... Или как?

Comment: Я его делал и глобальной переменной, та же ошибка

Comment: Воспользуйтесь самостоятельно утилитами для отлавливания подобных ошибок. Например, поищите по этому сайту слово "valgrind". Пригодится в любом случае, как и умение пользоваться отладчиком.

Comment: О, интересно, спасибо, надо глянуть)

Comment: "Ошибка при выделении памяти в Си"... Почему на вопросе стоит таг [C++]???

Comment: Просто я думаю, что людям, которые достаточно хорошо разбираются в C++ не составит труда разобраться и с этой проблемой. Тем более, учитывая то, что функция malloc есть и в С++

Comment: @NovaSurfer эта функция не из "С++" а из стандартной библиотеки С - `stdlib.h`

Comment: А как же `cstdlib` в C++?

Comment: @NovaSurfer, в C++ не приветствуется прямое управление памятью, и тем более - строительство велосипедов типа "свой список". И вопрос к C++ не имеет ни малейшего отношения, тем более что это всё-таки разные языки.

Comment: Спасибо, обожаю русскоязычные сообщества за доброту и ясность.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно не понятно, чего вы пытаетесь добиться создавая списки для *локального* указателя `Head` в каждой из своих функций типа `addCustomer` и никак не возвращая его наружу. Как эти функции собираются общаться между собой (а по замыслу они должны общаться между собой) - не ясно.

Что касается падения, то налицо популярная ошибка

```
PCust NewCustomer = (PCust)malloc(sizeof(PCust));
```

вызванная типичными и легко узнаваемыми "манерами" низкокачественного кода. В данном случае - использование имени типа под `sizeof` и сокрытие указательного типа под `typedef`

У вас `PCust` - это тип-указатель. Соответственно ваш `malloc(sizeof(PCust))` выделяет память под один указатель, а не под структуру `struct Customer`. Вам нужно `sizeof(struct Customer)` байтов памяти, а не `sizeof(PCust)`.

Как минимум исправьте размер в этом `malloc`.

А лучше - уберите из кода нафиг тип `PCust` - не надо скрывать указательные типы под `typedef` именами (это бывает полезно, но отнюдь не в таких контекстах). Сделайте `typedef` на `struct Customer`, если вам так уж хочется более короткой записи

```
typedef struct Customer Customer;
```

И научитесь пользоваться идиомой

```
T *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
```

В вашем случае

```
Customer *NewCustomer = malloc(sizeof *NewCustomer);
```

Также отдельная белиберда написана в `AddFirst`. Должно быть

```
void AddFirst(PCust * Head, PCust NewCustomer){
    NewCustomer->next = *Head;
    *Head = NewCustomer;
    // а не `Head = &NewCustomer`
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, переделал, все работает.
Странно, я это все брал из лекций от Mail.ru технострим.
Вот момент с созданием нового узла в спике: [https://youtu.be/LTr1vCF7IBA?t=23m25s](https://youtu.be/LTr1vCF7IBA?t=23m25s)
Аж обидно.

Comment: `Head` сделал глобальной

Comment: @NovaSurfer: И? Вы не замечаете, что под `malloc` в этом видео стоит `sizeof(Node)`, а не `sizeof(PNode)`? Также им простительно приведение типа на результат `malloc`, ибо речь идет, как я понял, о С++. Но `PNode` вместо `Node *` - это фейл.

Comment: Заметил **:|**.